# Webcam Performance System Test - WNCameraRequirements - Error: parseEtl Failed with error REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154)

Tags: windows, camera, performance-testing, etw

I am running whck performance tests on our camera, the test that currently fails is:
[Webcam Performance System Test - WNCameraRequirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn375917.aspx)

the test iterates thourgh the camera media types and records a etl file as expected, its stops and closes the camera but then the test fails due to the parsing of the etl file, the logs:

> Start Operation:  parseEtl average 250 endGuid
>   {B8197C10-845F-40ca-82AB-9341E98CFC2B} endId 215 max 275 name Time to
>   switch Preview MediaTypes scenario DiffEventSeries skip 1 startGuid
>   {B8197C10-845F-40ca-82AB-9341E98CFC2B} startId 243
>
> Parsing Etl: previewIterateMediaTypes_7-20_10-22-58.etl
>
> Warning: CoCreateInstance(CLSID_EtwFilter, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IEtwFilter,
>   (void**)spEtwFilter.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()) failed with 
>   REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154)
>
> Warning: 
>   * File: testsrc\multimediatest\common\helpers\capture\videocaptureperf\videocaptureperf.cpp
>   Ln: 260
>
> Warning: DiffEventSeries( etlFileName, pszStartEventGuid,
>   startId, pszEndEventGuid, endId, &min, &max, &ave, skip,
>   m_spLog.Get()) failed with REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154)
>
> Warning: 
>   * File: testsrc\multimediatest\common\helpers\capture\captureengine\captureengineautomation.cpp
>   Ln: 2109
>
> Error: parseEtl Failed with error REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
>   (0x80040154)

I tried searcing for a missing dll for ETW but I found nothing related. seems like theres a bug in the whck test while trying to parse the generated etl file... is this Error seems familier to anyone??
thanks!

Comment: Do you try googling CLSID_EtwFilter ?

Comment: which windows do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the wrong whql tests platform version (needed x64), and I needed to regsvr32 etwpatterns.dll. that being said, this test is filtered out by microsoft [(whql filters)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh998024.aspx) so we eventually ignored it.